# How do I fix my auto-completion in VSCODE?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

In the example below you can see that my auto-completion is not "full", but only partial.

I have a couple of extensions that might affect this, which is why I posted them below the gif.
I have already tried to change it in VSCode settings in vain.

[Autocompletion failed][1]

VSCode Extensions:

1. Python
2. Kite
3. Visual Studio IntelliCode
4. Python Extended
   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9eYm2.gif

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, if you type `main`, there is a

```
Code snippet for a `if __name__ == "__main__": ...` block
```

which gets the whole code completion, so the function auto-completion is recognized by some keywords:

[image]

You can install **Pylance** in extension marketplace. Pylance provides some awesome features for Python 3, including Code completion, Parameter suggestions and others. More information you can refer to [Pylance](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release).

Comment: Thanks a lot! The reason my example above did not work was that it is a kite pro feature and my kite trial expired. I have another question regarding your answer:
Is there a website or a place where I can see all the code snippets from the "Python" extension?

Comment: look at this: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/blob/master/snippets/python.json

Comment: That's really helpful! Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

My auto-complete also didn't work today, but it was because I had kite enabled without kite engine installed thus even Kite didn't work.

You might have some other needed software missing like I did.
Keep a look out for error messages about these autocomplete extensions to see if you might be missing some dependencies.

Otherwise you might have to try disabling or uninstalling some of these extensions and for example only keeping IntelliCode.